# Convert json array in js

Tags: javascript

I want to convert below array of json object to .Note the id and tagId.Whats the best way to do this is js

```
[{
    "id": 10,
    "mj": 0,
    "mi": 1,
    "name": "TEST (1)",
    "number": "INBOX-0004",
    "filename": "TEST (1).png"
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "mj": 0,
    "mi": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "number": "0003",
    "filename": "test.csv"

}]
```

to

```
[{
    "tagId": 10,
    "mj": 0,
    "mi": 1

}, {
    "tagId": 9,
    "mj": 0,
    "mi": 1

}]
```

Comment: 1. `JSON.parse` 2. `Array.prototype.map` 2. `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map()` to return desired result.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 10,
  "mj": 0,
  "mi": 1,
  "name": "TEST (1)",
  "number": "INBOX-0004",
  "filename": "TEST (1).png"
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "mj": 0,
  "mi": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "number": "0003",
  "filename": "test.csv"
}];

var result = data.map(function(e) {
  return {tagId: e.id, mj: e.mj, mi: e.mi}
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: And then don't forget `JSON.stringify(result);`